# Docker not running Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I've installed docker on a fresh machine and used the following tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-20-04

I have the following output.

```
~/code » sudo systemctl status docker                                                                               ben@bagley
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-08-10 10:36:50 BST; 3s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 19143 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 20
     Memory: 28.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─19143 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

However, when I run

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app?with=mysql,redis" | bash
```

I get the following: `Docker is not running.`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You use `sudo systemctl status docker` to confirm docker is running, means you are not in `root` I guess.

And if you execute `curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app?with=mysql,redis"` directly, you could see next:

```
docker info > /dev/null 2>&1

# Ensure that Docker is running...
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Docker is not running."

    exit 1
fi
......
```

Means the curl will download a script, and the log `Docker is not running.` is print due to not execute `docker info` correctly when execute that script.

As you are not `root`, so defintely the `docker info` could not be run. You have next 3 options to choose to make it work:

**Option 1:**

`sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}` to add current user to docker group, then exit current shell, login the shell again to run the `curl` command with root.

**Option 2:**

`curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app?with=mysql,redis" | sudo bash`

**Option 3:**

`sudo -s -H` to switch to root, then execute the curl command.

Comment: Option 1 is the desired solution. If that single line doesn't fix it, check the other steps in the [Docker guide on setting up non-root access](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/).

Comment: `option 3`  works like rocket. thank you mate

Comment: I recommend stopping docker and running it without sudo. If you use Option 2 you can run into a slew of permission errors after the install